# Is it possible to add textfield to an array?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've set up a macro to convert Word tables to array, but some of the cells contain empty text form fields. I'm wondering if there is a way to include these in a VBA array? Other tables have mixed string and field, which may be a separate problem, I thought I'd start with the simplest version first.

The end goal is to try to get a table with Autocorrect codes in one column and Autocorrect text in the other to automatically get added to Proofing/Autocorrect via AutoCorrect.Entries.AddRichText.

I took a look at the [FormField object description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.formfield) since this seemed on topic, and I could see how I might use the Add method to insert fields directly into a selection area. But this doesn't help get a field in an array.

I found an [enumeration for word fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.wdfieldtype) but that likewise doesn't seem useful to add field to an array.

```
' ... var set up omitted

ReDim MyT(TRow - 1, TCol - 1) As Variant

' ... looping through cells of table code omitted

OCell.Select
If Selection.Fields.Count > 0 Then
    MyT(A, B) = wdFieldFormTextInput 
Else
    MyT(A, B) = Selection.Text
End If
```

I have a later function that displays the array, but for the code above it just subs in the enum value of 70 for the wdFieldFormTextInput, which makes sense but was definitely not what I was hoping for.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for / what you're trying to do. Can you provide some sort of example of what the source is, what result you're getting and the result you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you are after just the text of the field you might be able to use:

`ActiveDocument.Range.TextRetrievalMode.IncludeFieldCodes = False`

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.textretrievalmode

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new `FormField` by adding it to the `FormFields` collection, and also add the new `FormField` to array `a`.

```
Dim a(1 To 1) As FormField
Set a(1) = FormFields.Add(Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldFormCheckBox)
```

Is this what you want to do?